# csv writer leaves empty output file when the python script crashes

Tags: python, csv, writer

I have a script that runs some analysis on files, then write the results to a CSV file. In pseudo code:

```
while (there are still files to analyze): 
  do_analysis
  writer.writerow({... lots of columns names and the analysis results data... })
```

If the script completes, the data is indeed in the csv file.
But if the script crashes - the files are empty. But the writer.writerow() line is called after each file analysis is complete, so I was expecting to get data in the csv file for all files that were analysed before the crash.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than pseudo-code? Otherwise, it's going to be near impossible to replicate your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writerow does not instantly write to the file, most of the writing is done when closing the file.
You can enforce the writing to the file with

```
file.flush()
```

do this whenever you want to save your writings to the file.

For further information https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_flush.htm

Comment: Thanks! This did the job. Note for newbies like me:

The csv file was opened like this:
 with open(csvfilename, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:

Therefore I use:

csv_file.flush()